# NLTK bigram formatting / Reading file word by word

Tags: python, nltk

I'm getting word pairs, to then create a node-link diagram.

For my node-link diagram to work my pairs need to come out in this format

```
graph = ('one','two'),('two','three'),('three','one')
```

I'm either going wrong with how I'm using NTLK to get my pairing or how I'm reading the file

```
f = open("test.txt","r")
string = f.read()
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(string)
pairs = [ " ".join(pair) for pair in nltk.bigrams(tokens)]
print (pairs)
#['one two', 'two three', 'three one']
```

Here just trying to do it a different way but now it's reading the file character by character

```
f = open("test.txt","r")
string = f.read()
a = nltk.bigrams(string)
print (list(a))
#[('o', 'n'), ('n', 'e'), ('e', ' '), (' ', 't'), ('t', 'w'), ('w', 'o'), ('o', ' '), (' ', 't'), ('t', 'h'), ('h', 'r'), ('r', 'e'), ('e', 'e'), ('e', ' '), (' ', 'o'), ('o', 'n'), ('n', 'e')]
```

Now trying to read the file word by word

```
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split(" "):
            print (word)
```

But this is now doing it word by word, on separate lines so now I get

```
#[('o', 'n'), ('n', 'e')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your first solution is close.
Why the join?

Here an example to solve your issue

```
import nltk
test = "one two tree four"

test_token = nltk.word_tokenize(test)
print(test_token)
bgram= nltk.bigrams(test_token)
print(list(bgram))
```

produces:

```
['one', 'two', 'tree', 'four']
[('one', 'two'), ('two', 'tree'), ('tree', 'four')]
```